# What colour is my friend's house?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

One of my friends, Anne, is staying in London. She had told me which street she is in but, to my understanding, there are a huge number of houses in the same street. Fortunately, every house in this street has a colour and no two share the same colour. She told me that:

> rdo eyw gn? iov t, 13×r+13×s+13×w+13×g

What colour is her house?

Hint:

> Addition of the two codes

Comment: Please don't change the puzzle after you post it.

Comment: So can we have a hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deepthinker101 has gotten part way but I think the colour of the house is

> GREY

First part

> As Deepthinker101 pointed out the first sequence of letters, when taken in pairs, gives **rd, oe, yw, gn, ?, io, vt** which represent the first/last letter pairs of the colours of the rainbow and the missing set is **be** representing the colour **BLUE**

Second part

> If we take rot13 of the given letters **RSWG**, we get **EFJT**.
>  This does not mean much on its own but if we add the alphabetical positions **EFJT=(5,6,10,20)** to the letter positions of the word **BLUE = (2,12,21,5)** we get **(7,18,31,25)**, or modulo 26, **(7,18,5,25)** which encodes the letters **GREY**

Comment: Dammit should not have fallen asleep.

Comment: Haha I'm so sorry I edited this question early in the morning at 6:30 AM!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> The first statement hints at blue: the letters are organised to spell the letters of the rainbow in order rEd oRANGe yELLOw  gREEn iNDIGo vIOLEt and so the missing colour is blue.

Comment: Yes I am finally back from a long hiatus

Comment: That also fits with the position of the ? and the original clue that was edited out (3665?66) so safe to say that's correct

Comment: Yes it's true I'm afraid to say that the previous clue is way harder

Comment: May I have a hint for the second half?

Comment: My first thought was rot13 the letters, but that didn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: That is what I did too